# @StackChemistry Twitter Account

Tags: discussion, support

There is a [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackChemistry) (@StackChemistry) for this website which frequently tweets Questions and Answers .
Recently while editing a [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/24928/revisions) of mine I came across this :

```
    Tweeted twitter.com/#!/StackChemistry/status/569049562998034433 occurred Feb 21 at 8:22
```

So,
Who controls this account ?
Which questions are tweeted ?
Why are there [350+ avid users](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4964/chemistry) and only 55 followers of that account ? (just a rhetoric )

Comment: Hey, who knows? Maybe a user isn't "avid" yet, but is following that account. Still, due to censorship and stupid stuff like that, I can't follow, even if I want to. (Not that I like to do so. :P Seriously, what's the point in following it?)

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bot. I think it tweets question/answer pairs with some number of votes on both, or questions with a high vote count but no answer.

Comment: Looks convincing.

Comment: @DelPate the bot, or Manish, or the answer? :)

Comment: Why can't I be all three?

Comment: @ManishEarth Because bots don't go mad on good questions while we do.

Comment: @MARamezani The bot's work :)

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if the Twitter account pulled any images from questions to make them more attractive to twitter users and also included more information about the question.

From
@StackChemistry account:
[image: Example from @StackChemistry account]

Example that I think could potentially solicit more interest from Twitter
[image: Example that I think would solicit more responses]

Comment: +1, Looks like a good idea. I think opening a new question on meta will garner more views/opinions than as an answer to a question with an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that!